# Laravel 5.3 middleware

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

Здравствуйте,у меня такой вопрос.Можно ли передать переменную из Middleware в Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В laravel 5.x вы можете использовать `$request->merge` для добавления параметров в Rquest,или изменить существующий `$request->replace(array('inputname' => 'new value'));`.

Если вы пытаетесь это сделать в [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware) то должны помнить что их бывает двух типов.

**1.Ваш вариант это *Before Middleware։***

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //....
    $request->merge(array("input_name" => "input_value"));

    return $next($request);
}
```

И в контроллере:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // ...
    $my_var1 = $request->input('input_name');
    // Так тоже можно получить добавленное значение
    $my_var2 = Request::instance()->query('input_name');
    // ...
}
```

**2. *After Middleware* выполнит свою задачу после обработки Request:**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    // Request обрабатывается до этой строчки.
    // Поэтому делать что либо с Request уже бессмысленно
    $request->merge(array("input_name" => "input_value"));

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ вы мне очень помогли